# How to get priority of a task using microsoft graph api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have created tasks in microsoft planner through micrsoft graph api. I am not able to retrieve the priority of the tasks. Which field should be looked into ?

Answer (score 5):

The priority property on task is currently only on the [beta endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannertask?view=graph-rest-beta). We're working on updating V1.0 endpoint with the new properties from beta. You can use it from there in the meantime, this one is going to be moved to v1.0 as is.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by calling beta endpoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/planner/tasks
```

Priority of tasks is valid range of values is between 0 and 10 (inclusive), with increasing value being lower priority (0 has the highest priority and 10 has the lowest priority). Currently, Planner interprets values 0 and 1 as "urgent", 2 and 3 and 4 as "important", 5, 6, and 7 as "medium", and 8, 9, and 10 as "low". Currently, Planner sets the value 1 for "urgent", 3 for "important", 5 for "medium", and 9 for "low".

Answer (score 0):

FYI This is now available in the v1.0 version. I am using the 4.29 version of the Graph SDK and it is in there.